# This script require root privileges! | what is going on ?

Tags: ros, linux

I run the following command to install GeographicLib datasets for mavros inside the catkin_ws directory (catkin workspace).

```
./src/mavros/mavros/scripts/install_geographiclib_datasets.sh
This script require root privileges!
```

but I get that message in return. what does it mean and how to get the above mavros dependency(GeographicLib datasets) installed successfully?
Before this command, I followed the source installation process as mentioned [here](https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/blob/master/mavros/README.md).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it with sudo:

`sudo ./src/mavros/mavros/scripts/install_geographiclib_datasets.sh`